# Taking a range as a struct field

Tags: rust, traits

There are multiple `Range` types. Some `Range` types implement `Iterator`. I want to take all `Range` types that implement `Iterator` as a struct field.

This is my approach:

```rust
pub trait RangeBoundsExt<T: PartialOrd<T>>: Iterator<Item = T> {
    // some methods
}

impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::Range<T> {}

impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::RangeFrom<T> {}

impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::RangeInclusive<T> {}

pub struct Foo<T> {
    range: Box<dyn RangeBoundsExt<T>>
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ead950b76fedd5b90100bd275ea4803)

But I am getting this error:

```
  Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::iter::Step` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:7:24
  |
7 | impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::Range<T> {}
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::iter::Step` is not implemented for `T`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::ops::Range<T>`
help: consider further restricting this bound
  |
7 | impl<T: PartialOrd<T> + std::iter::Step> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::Range<T> {}
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::iter::Step` is not satisfied
 --> src/lib.rs:9:24
  |
9 | impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::RangeFrom<T> {}
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::iter::Step` is not implemented for `T`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::ops::RangeFrom<T>`
help: consider further restricting this bound
  |
9 | impl<T: PartialOrd<T> + std::iter::Step> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::RangeFrom<T> {}
  |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0277]: the trait bound `T: std::iter::Step` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:11:24
   |
11 | impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::RangeInclusive<T> {}
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::iter::Step` is not implemented for `T`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::ops::RangeInclusive<T>`
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
11 | impl<T: PartialOrd<T> + std::iter::Step> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::RangeInclusive<T> {}
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 3 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Range` does not guarantee an `Iterator` implementation. It only provides one if the type implements `Step`. Likewise, `RangeTo` does not guarantee a lack of an `Iterator` implementation. It simply just doesn't provide one by default. To fix your error, you simply have to require that there is an iterator definition for the range:

```rust
// note the additional 'where' requirement
impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::Range<T> where
    std::ops::Range<T>: Iterator<Item = T>
{
}

impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::RangeFrom<T> where
    std::ops::RangeFrom<T>: Iterator<Item = T>
{
}

impl<T: PartialOrd<T>> RangeBoundsExt<T> for std::ops::RangeInclusive<T> where
    std::ops::RangeInclusive<T>: Iterator<Item = T>
{
}
```